# ffmpeg dedot filter: any examples or documentation

Tags: ffmpeg

I have some videos that exhibit "dot crawl".  I'm sure others do as well.
There is an ffmpeg filter "dotcrawl" which should be useful.  My copy of
ffmpeg has this filter built in.  The problem is, there are no examples
and the documentation is not sufficient.  The documentation can be found
at:

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#dedot

but all it says is:

11.59 dedot

Reduce cross-luminance (dot-crawl) and cross-color (rainbows) from video.

It accepts the following options:

m

```
Set mode of operation. Can be combination of dotcrawl for cross-luminance reduction and/or rainbows for cross-color reduction.
```

lt

```
Set spatial luma threshold. Lower values increases reduction of cross-luminance.
```

tl

```
Set tolerance for temporal luma. Higher values increases reduction of cross-luminance.
```

tc

```
Set tolerance for chroma temporal variation. Higher values increases reduction of cross-color.
```

ct

```
Set temporal chroma threshold. Lower values increases reduction of cross-color.
```

It doesn't give the range for the values, nor does it say how to use more than
one variable.

By experiment, I have found that

-vf "dedot=dotcrawl"

is accepted: but

-vf "dedot=dotcrawl:t1=1"

is rejected.  This is the syntax that works for many other filters, such as

"eq=brightness=0.1:contrast=1.25"

and so on.

The other documentation I have found is:

https://www.aquilinestudios.org/avsfilters/dotcrawl.html

which discusses a DeDot filter, but the arguments are different
than what is in the ffmpeg documentation.

The source code is apparently at:

https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavfilter/vf_dedot.c

but it is somewhat less than completely illuminating, as the source
code contains no comments.

(I spent many years as a developer and project manager, and I would
never accept something like this into a project.  But I digress...)

Could anyone please explain how to use this filter, and what the
arguments mean?  As I said, I'm sure this would be useful to many
people if it were documented.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in your example, you used t1, not tl. You need a lower case "L", not a number 1.

There is marginally more information using the command

```
ffmpeg -h filter=dedot
```

with the output:

```
Filter dedot
  Reduce cross-luminance and cross-color.
    slice threading supported
    Inputs:
       #0: default (video)
    Outputs:
       #0: default (video)
dedot AVOptions:
   m                 <flags>      ..FV....... set filtering mode (default dotcrawl+rainbows)
     dotcrawl                     ..FV.......
     rainbows                     ..FV.......
   lt                <float>      ..FV....... set spatial luma threshold (from 0 to 1) (default 0.079)
   tl                <float>      ..FV....... set tolerance for temporal luma (from 0 to 1) (default 0.079)
   tc                <float>      ..FV....... set tolerance for chroma temporal variation (from 0 to 1) (default 0.058)
   ct                <float>      ..FV....... set temporal chroma threshold (from 0 to 1) (default 0.019)

This filter has support for timeline through the 'enable' option.
```

So this gives the range and default values for each parameter.
Better documentation with examples is at the AviSynth.nl wiki for the dedot filter.

http://avisynth.nl/index.php/DeDot

But this documentation requires some conversions from ffmpeg to Avisynth values.

```
ffmpeg, value* avisynth max= avisynth val, avisynth name

lt      .079   255           20            luma2d
tl      .079   255           20            lumaT
tc      .058   255           15            chromaT1
ct      .015   255            5            chromaT2
```

Interestingly, the ffmpeg git source code for the dedot filter converts the floating point values back to the avisynth values (and uses the avisynth variable names!) before operating on a frame.

Now for some ffmpeg examples using the dedot filter. The common start is

```
ffmpeg.exe -hide_banner -y -ss 60 -t 30 -i intest.mp4 -map v:0
```

which reads as: Suppress ffmpeg banner, overwrite output, start encoding from 60 seconds and encode 30 seconds of the input intest.mp4. Select the first video track.
Then add the dedot part:

```
 -vf dedot                         # dedot both rainbows and dot crawl using default values
 -vf dedot=dotcrawl:tc=0.0:ct=1.0  # dedot reducing dot crawl only
 -vf dedot=rainbows:lt=1.0:tl=0.0  # dedot reducing rainbows only
```

followed by e.g.

```
 -c:v libx264 -crf 21 -map a:0 -c:a copy outtest.x264.mkv
```

which reads: Transcode input using libx264 video encoder at constant rate factor 21, and select and copy the first audio track to the outtest.x264.mkv file.

A complete line is

```
ffmpeg.exe -hide_banner -y -ss 180 -t 30 -i intest.mp4 -map v:0 -vf dedot -c:v libx264 -crf 21 -map a:0 -c:a copy outtest.x264.mkv
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your clarification.  I'm going to try this out very soon.